# Get value from data-set field sublist

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset (that pull its data from a dict) that I am attempting to clean and republish. Within this data set, there is a field with a sublist that I would like to extract specific data from.

Here's the data:

```
[{'id': 'oH58h122Jpv47pqXhL9p_Q', 'alias': 'original-pizza-brooklyn-4', 'name': 'Original Pizza', 'image_url': 'https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/HVT0Vr_Vh52R_niODyPzCQ/o.jpg', 'is_closed': False, 'url': 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/original-pizza-brooklyn-4?adjust_creative=IelPnWlrTpzPtN2YRie19A&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=IelPnWlrTpzPtN2YRie19A', 'review_count': 102, 'categories': [{'alias': 'pizza', 'title': 'Pizza'}], 'rating': 4.0, 'coordinates': {'latitude': 40.63781, 'longitude': -73.8963799}, 'transactions': [], 'price': '$', 'location': {'address1': '9514 Ave L', 'address2': '', 'address3': '', 'city': 'Brooklyn', 'zip_code': '11236', 'country': 'US', 'state': 'NY', 'display_address': ['9514 Ave L', 'Brooklyn, NY 11236']}, 'phone': '+17185313559', 'display_phone': '(718) 531-3559', 'distance': 319.98144420799355},
```

Here's how the data is presented within the csv/spreadsheet:

```
location
{'address1': '9514 Ave L', 'address2': '', 'address3': '', 'city': 'Brooklyn', 'zip_code': '11236', 'country': 'US', 'state': 'NY', 'display_address': ['9514 Ave L', 'Brooklyn, NY 11236']}
```

Is there a way to pull location.city for example?

The below code simply adds a few fields and exports it to a csv.

```
def data_set(data):

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['zip'] = get_zip()
    df['region'] = get_region()

    newdf = df.filter(['name', 'phone', 'location', 'zip', 'region', 'coordinates', 'rating', 'review_count',
                       'categories', 'url'], axis=1)

    if not os.path.isfile('yelp_data.csv'):
        newdf.to_csv('data.csv', header='column_names')
    else:  # else it exists so append without writing the header
        newdf.to_csv('data.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

If that doesn't make sense, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This appears to be a dictionary, in which case you can index into it with the key to get the value; `location['city']`

Comment: Thanks for your response! How do I filter the df and index into it?

Comment: My first instinct is to add a column; `df['city']=df['location'].apply(lambda x: x['city'])` and then include that in the filter